# Python- applying arithmetic to numbers in a text file without split

Tags: python, file, io, strip, arithmetic-expressions

I'm working on take numbers in a text file and subtracting 255 from the number, but keeping the absolute value.

```
    def negate(char):
    '''
    absolute value of RGB value - 255
    '''
    line = int(char)
    negate_line = line - 255
    negate_line = abs(negate_line)
    negate_line = str(negate_line)
    return negate_line


`def process_body(infile, outfile, modification):`
    '''

    '''
    for line in infile.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        for char in line:
            print(char, end="")
            # for debugging purposes. press enter to print next character in line
            input()


            if modification == "apply": 
                negate(line)
                outfile.write(negate)
```

I know I'm supposed to do something with string method in order to get the numbers by themselves, but I haven't been able to find a way to separate the numbers without using `.split`. The only string method aloud is .strip

The char in the negate function should be the value returned once I figure out a loop to separate the numbers in the text file, but I currently don't have a value because I have not figured out the loop yet.

The textfile looks like

```
0 44 89 0 44 89 0 44 89 0 44 89 1 45 90 
1 45 90 1 45 90 1 45 90 1 45 92 1 45 92
```

Comment: `line = line.split()` instead of `line.strip()`?

Comment: I cannot use the .split according to my teachers instructions

Comment: Then edit your question: "According to the instructions, I cannot use any string method besides .split"

Comment: Sorry, I've been working on this so long the words get jumbled

Comment: My advice would be to keep working at it instead of looking for the answer here. Set your computer aside for a moment and do this with pen and paper pretending you can only do things like check what the character is (hint: `if char == " "` what do you want to do? Or, perhaps it's easier for you to think about what happens when `char != " "`

Comment: I've been messing around with that a little too. I think I understand that if char == " " then it will count each number separately, but is there a way to index each one according to the spaces? `i = [ ] ` before the loop?

Comment: Hmm. Here's another hint. You will start with `num = ""` Then each iteration of the inner for-loop, you either find a `" "` or another char, which you know is a digit. So, then `num = num + char` where the `+` operator is *concatenating* not adding: `"2" + "2" == "22"`

Comment: That's the right track... think about where you have to start with `num = ""`. Also, what happens to `num` when you encounter `" "`?

Comment: Instead of printing char, print `num` to debug..

Comment: Shouldn't returning num and changing it into an int allow me to apply the arithmetic?
`  num = ""
    for line in infile.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        for char in line:
            print(char, end="")
            if char != " " :
                num = num + char
                return num`
The negate function where the math is happening is 
`def negate(num):
    '''
    absolute value of RGB value - 255
    '''
    line = int(num)
    negate_line = line - 255
    negate_line = abs(negate_line)
    negate_line = str(negate_line)
    return negate_line
`

Comment: This is my first time using this website, so if theres an easier way for me to show you my code, I would love to make it easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def negate(num):
'''
absolute value of RGB value - 255
'''
line = int(num)
negate_line = line - 255
negate_line = abs(negate_line)
negate_line = str(negate_line)
return negate_line
```

and

```
def process_body(infile, outfile, modification):
'''

'''

num = ""
space = " "
for line in infile.readlines():
    line = line.strip()
    s = line + space
    for char in line:
        print(char, end="")
        if char == space :
            num += s[num +1]



        # for debugging purposes. press enter to print next character in line
        input() 

        print(num, end="")
        # for debugging purposes. press enter to print next character in line
        input()

        if modification == "negate": 
            negate_line = negate(num)
            outfile.write(negate_line)

        if modification == "high contrast":
            hc = high_contrast(num)
            outfile.write(hc)
```

My current output is 
0

0
4
04
4
044

044
8
0448
9
04489

But I need to be getting numbers like these

255 211 166 255 211

So this isn't quite an answer, but I'm not sure whats going wrong

Comment: Please don't post an answer as an extension to your question to indicate that something else is wrong. Please delete this.